# Visualize Sentences Vector in 2D using Python

Tags: python, nlp

If I have sentences vector of TF-IDF of words then how I can plot that in 2D graph?

Answer (score 1):

Run singular value decomposition on your array of TF-IDF vectors, then recompose them using the first two components. This will create 2 dimensional representations which you can then visualize:

```python
U, s, Vt = np.linalg.svd(tf_idf_array)
projections = np.dot((U[:,:2]), np.dot(np.diag(s[:2]), Vt.T))
```

Beware that SVD is a costy operation for large arrays and may not converge if the array is sparse.